# Segmentation fault (core dumped) QgsApplication

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, standalone

```
import os, os.path,sys
from    qgis.core   import  *
from    qgis.gui    import  *
from    PyQt4.QtGui import  *
from    PyQt4.QtCore    import  *


class   MapExplorer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Landmark Explorer")
        self.resize(800,    400)


def main():

    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'], True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    app =   QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  =   MapExplorer()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()
    app.exec_()
    app.deleteLater()
    QgsApplication.exitQgis()


if  __name__    =="__main__":
    main()
```

Then run this code and get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What did I do wrong?

OpenSuse 42.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your initialisation the wrong way round. Try:

```
app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

Note also the creation of a `QgsApplication`, not a `QApplication`.

You might still get a seg fault when the application exits because I don't think you've cleaned up properly, but my adjustment above should pop up your main window.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```